# Hugo Theme Error

Tags: web, themes, hugo

I receive the following error when running "hugo -t minimo":

```
ERROR 2017/10/10 18:25:34 Error while rendering "page": template: theme/_default/single.html:1:3: executing "theme/_default/single.html" at <partial "header" .>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/header.html:4:3: executing "theme/partials/header.html" at <partial "head/head" ...>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/head/head.html:2:5: executing "theme/partials/head/head.html" at <partial "head/meta" ...>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/head/meta.html:5:3: executing "theme/partials/head/meta.html" at <partial "head/opengr...>: error calling partial: template: theme/partials/head/opengraph.html:102:12: executing "theme/partials/head/opengraph.html" at <.admins>: range can't iterate over
```

Hugo and the theme is up-to-date. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your TOML configuration make sure that the admins array is empty or set correctly with a comma seperated list of strings.

`admins = [] # array of Facebook IDs`

If that does not solve your problem, then update to latest version of the Hugo executable. [latest](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases)

Comment: `code[params.opengraph]
  [params.opengraph.facebook]
    admins = ""`

Comment: should be an array